# Cyclic group ( subgroup )

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image: this is 2.3 Thm 7 from Dummit and foot . Abstract Algebra]

I am trying to prove (2) , but I do not have an idea . Would someone walk out through this proof . Thanks in advance

Comment: Keep in mind the premise of the Theorem, that $H$ is cyclic, still applies.  Do you know an example of a cyclic group $H$ with $|H|=\infty$?

Comment: Now that looks familiar. Is it possible Richard Foote's text? He was my prof.

Comment: Z with additive generator 1

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod that's right. So, you may want to write up the proof for me. Since he did not include it in the book.

Comment: Not  chance that I would upload the proof for you. But this is not difficult. There are basically three parts, did you get the first part?

Comment: The first and third part are already written in the book .

Comment: I'm talking about (2) having three parts.

Comment: $|H|$ means $(H,\times) \simeq (\mathbb{Z},+)$ (this is the exercice needed to prove 2)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If a and b are distinct (consider 2 and 6 for example) then the set of all multiples of a is different from the set of all multiples of b.

Multiples of m are the same as the multiples of |m|. Note, when I say multiples I mean both positive and negative multiples.

Comment: So the bijection is between what and $\Bbb N$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $H=\langle x\rangle$ and let $|H|=\infty$. Further suppose there exists $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^a=x^b$. But then $x^{a-b}=1$ which implies the order of $x$ divides the finite amount $a-b$, which implies the order of $x$ is finite, a contradiction. Thus all powers of $x$ must be distinct.

Now consider $$\langle x^m\rangle=\{x^{am}\mid a\in\mathbb{Z}\}=\{x^{-a\cdot-m}\mid -a\in\mathbb{Z}\}=\langle x^{-m}\rangle.$$ Thus $\langle x^m\rangle=\langle x^{-m}\rangle=\langle x^{|m|}\rangle.$

Hopefully this is enough for you to finish it.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol $\langle x \rangle$ denotes the subgroup generated by $x$, which is the smallest subgroup containing $x$, which is the intersection of all subgroups containing $x$, which is $\{x^n : n\in \mathbb Z\}.$

For any distinct $a,b\in \mathbb Z$ and any $n\in \mathbb Z$ we have $n=n'(a-b)+n''$ for some integer $n'$ and some  integer $n''$ with  $0\leq n'' <|a-b|.$

Suppose $H=\langle x\rangle$ and $x^a=x^b$ for some distinct $a,b\in \mathbb Z$. Then for any $n\in \mathbb Z$ we have $$x^n=x^{n'(a-b)+n''}=(x^{(a-b)})^{n'}x^{n''}=$$ $$=1^{n'}x^{n''}=x^{n''}\in \{x^j :0\leq j<|a-b|\}$$ which implies  $H=\langle x \rangle\;\subseteq \;\{x^j :0\leq j<|a-b|\}$ and therefore $|H|\leq |a-b|+1<\infty.$

Comment: For unknown reason, in my first sentence  which reads "The symbol <x>..." in my draft, omits "<x>" in my post and I can't make it  show .

Comment: You can use `\langle x \rangle` for $\langle x \rangle$.

Comment: It shows up just fine  later in my A and I thought i just forgot to put it in the first line but when i went to edit, it was there in my draft but not in the "post" below it on the same screen. Random computer gremlin, or  (more likely) I hit a "special" key without realizing it